# Mongo search by last inserted items

Tags: mongodb

I have a documents structure like this

```
{
  _id: 1,
  userId: 10,
  tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  created: '2014-06-01'
},

{
  _id: 2,
  userId: 10,
  tags:   [],
  created: '2014-06-05'
}

{
  _id: 3,
  userId: 11,
  tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  created: '2014-05-29'
}
```

And I want to get result (search by tags) like this (search only by last inserted items).If last inserted item does not have tag it should not be displayed as a result of

```
{
    _id: 3,
   userId: 11,
   tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   created: '2014-06-02'
}
```

So, I tried to do it with the next query

```
db.users.find({tags: 'a'}).sort({created: -1})
```

and result looks like this

```
{
   _id: 3,
   userId: 11,
   tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
   created: '2014-06-02'
}

{
  _id: 1,
  userId: 10,
  tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  created: '2014-06-01'
}
```

but the result is not one that I expected... because last item does not have any tags

Comment: you're going to need to explain this a bit more. your second document re-uses the same userId as your earlier sample, but has a different "created" field and the syntax is invalid (you have an extra pair of "{" around it). not clear what your overall problem is - what is the desired result vs. what is returned by the query?

Comment: Main idea in order to search only in last inserted item.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you would like to search for the presence of a specific tag within the tags array but only searching within the very last document according to "created".

So two things you need to do:

1. Fix your "created" field. It's stored as a string and that won't do,
   as you can't easily compare dates stored as strings, so sorting
   won't work. So you'll need to fix that. Please check out the
   documentation of BSON Date types and also look at the documentation
   for whatever language/driver you are using.
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date
2. Use the aggregation framework. You can use the aggregation framework
   to perform this type of analysis. I've included sample code below,
   assuming your sample schema has been corrected with the proper Date
   format:

   {
     _id: 1,
     userId: 10,
     tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     created: ISODate("2014-06-01T10:50:42.389Z")
   }

   {
     _id: 2,
     userId: 10,
     tags:   [],
     created: ISODate("2014-06-05T12:30:48.389Z")
   }

   {
     _id: 3,
     userId: 11,
     tags:   ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     created: ISODate("2014-05-05T02:12:09.389Z")
   }

You can then run the following aggregation pipeline command:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
                     {$sort:{created:-1}}, 
                     {$limit:1}, 
                     {$match:{tags:"a"}}
                     ])
```

This will match nothing as the last document inserted by created does not have "a" in the tags array. If you then add a new document:

```
{
  _id: 4,
  userId: 11,
  tags:   ['a', 'c'],
  created: ISODate("2014-06-09T02:12:09.389Z")
}
```

which is now the latest created and has "a" in tags and run this command you get:

```
{ 
  "_id" : 4, 
  "userId" : 11, 
  "tags" : [ "a", "c" ], 
  "created" : ISODate("2014-06-09T02:12:09.389Z") 
}
```

Which is I believe the desired result. More on the aggregation framework here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

It is because the field `created` is not a valid Date type field in MongoDB.

You need to store the values in that field properly. One way could be to insert values like:

```
created : ObjectId().getTimestamp()
```

Now `created` will have a valid MongoDB Date value. To sort them in reverse chronological order all you've got to run is:

```
db.collection.find().sort({'created' : -1});
```

You can put something in find() to search for your specific documents. You did put a search on tags in your question. I've skipped it though. You have got the idea now for sure...

Comment: Thx for you comment. But, I need before search by tag, sort items in which will  search.

Comment: didn't understand... what do you mean?